# Proprietary Code, Make a pages code inaccessible

Tags: css, obfuscation, bundling-and-minification

Is there any way to hide or otherwise make inaccessible a web pages proprietary CSS code?  I know about minification but a minified css file can easily be unpacked.

Thank you for your help,
Marc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from minification and perhaps base64 encoding, there is nothing you can do to mask your CSS text.  And those are easily reversible.

There is no way to make it unreadable, as the browser has to be able to read it in order to display it, therefore the user can read it if they want to.

I think you are tackling the wrong problem.  Your problem shouldn't be "how do I prevent users from seeing my proprietary css code"  it should be "Why does my CSS code have anything proprietary in it."

It really shouldn't, and if it does you should fix that.

Comment: "*Why does my CSS code have anything proprietary in it.*" that's the most important statement. CSS is openly visible to the browser and to the end user, and there is nothing proprietary about it.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** The browser needs to be able to access the CSS in order to display the page correctly.

You could unpack the elements from the CSS and apply them inline instead. Not sure if that would solve your question though.